# Handling different logic based on type

Tags: c#

I have `class Foo<T>` and an instance method `Foo<T>.M` with return type `T` and signature `M(Bar bar)`. There is a constraint on `T` (`T : AbstractBaseClass`) so that I'm certain that `T` has a property `T.SomeProperty` (and a parameterless constructor constraint). Let's say that `M` has to set the value of `T.SomeProperty` based on `bar` as well on the concrete type of `T`. I do not want my code to look like

```
T t = new T();
if(typeof(T) == T1) {
     T.SomeProperty = // some function of bar
}
else if(typeof(T) == T2) {
     T.SomeProperty = // some function of bar
}
else if(typeof(T) == T3) {
     T.SomeProperty == // some function of bar
}
```

I do not want to put an instance method on `T` that takes in values from `Bar` to populate `T.SomeProperty` because that will make my `T`s have a dependency on some things that I do not want it to them a dependency on.

What is my best option here?

Here's what I mean:

```
class AbstractBaseClass {
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class Foo<T> where T : AbstractBaseClass, new() {
    public T M(Bar bar) {
        T t = new T();
        t.SomeProperty = // function of bar, typeof(T)
        return t;
    }
}
```

How to write `M` but avoid type-by-type logic on the type parameter `T`?

Edit:

What about this? This is riffing on [Corey's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337972/handling-different-logic-based-on-type/7338372#7338372):

```
interface ISomePropertyStrategy<T> {
    int GetSomeProperty(Bar bar);
}

class SomePropertyStrategyForConcreteClass1 :
    ISomePropertyStrategy<ConcreteClass1> {
    public int GetSomeProperty(Bar bar) { return bar.MagicValue + 73; }
}

class SomePropertyStrategyForConcreteClass2 :
    ISomePropertyStrategy<ConcreteClass2> {
    public int GetSomeProperty(Bar bar) { return bar.MagicValue - 12; }
}

class Foo<T> where T : AbstractBaseClass, new() {
    private readonly ISomePropertyStrategy<T> strategy;
    public Foo<T>(ISomePropertyStrategy<T> strategy) {
        this.stragety = strategy;
    }
    public T M(Bar bar) {
        T t = new T();
        t.SomeProperty = this.strategy.GetSomeProperty(bar);
        return t;
    }
 }
```

The only thing I don't like about this is that it uses a generic interface where the generic type parameter never appears in the interface. I think I once saw a comment from Eric Lippert where he said that wasn't a good idea, but I can't remember. Sorry.

Comment: You could have a method in AbstractBaseClass, something like Apply(Bar b) that would set SomeProperty for you that can be overloaded, of course...  Or accept a projection like Func<Bar, int>.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: That makes `AbstractBaseClass` have a dependency on `Bar` which I don't want.

Comment: I see, then I'd go with the projection model in my comment, which is similar to Paul's answer below.

Comment: You won't be able to cast up from a generic type, so you can't rely on a concrete method that is not defined in the base class.

Comment: Well, why have an interface with a parameter that is used *nowhere* for *no purpose*? How does your program change if you simply remove the type parameter from ISomePropertyStrategy?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I can have a class `SomePropertyStrategyForConcreteClass1 : ISomePropertyStrategy<ConcreteClass1>` which is a strategy that is specific to the type `ConcreteClass1` and the compiler enforces for me that I don't try to use it for a different `T` in `Foo<T>`. And IoC containers will inject the right one for me based on the type I request (if I request `Foo<ConcreteClass1>` and have registered `SomePropertyStrategyForConcreteClass1` for `ISomePropertyStrategy<ConcreteClass1>` then my container will inject into `Foo<ConcreteClass1>`. Remove the type parameter, I lose both of these.

Answer (score 2):

So you have this:

```
class Foo<T>
    where T : AbstractBaseClass, new()
{
    T M( Bar bar )
    {
        T t = new T();

        if ( typeof (T) == T1 )
        {
            t.SomeProperty = bar.SomeMethod();
        }
        else if ( typeof (T) == T2 )
        {
            t.SomeProperty = bar.SomeOtherMethod();
        }
        else if ( typeof (T) == T3 )
        {
            t.SomeProperty == bar.YetAnotherMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

You could do this:

```
T M( Bar bar, Func<object> barFunction )
{
    T t = new T();

    t.SomeProperty = barFunction();
}
```

It doesn't require tight coupling with your Bar method. [Here is some information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) on the `Func<T>` delegate.

Comment: Not quite. There isn't a method on `Bar` that produces the values depending on the type. Sorry for not being clear; I can see how you can got that from "`// some function of bar`" but that's not what I meant.

Comment: Okay, the downside to this is that if someone news up a `Foo<T>` and given a `Bar` named `bar` calls `M`, they now need to know what `Func<object>` to pass to `M`. So it now becomes possible for that logic to become duplicated, or even accidentally differ if it's called from two different places.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a complete program. For the sake of the example, I take Bar to be some class that holds an interesting value (here, 100). I take foo.M to be a routine that wants to add 73 to the number inside Bar if the type argument is ConcreteClass1; it will want to subtract 12 from the number inside Bar if the type argument is ConcreteClass2.

The interface IABCVisitor and the virtual methods AcceptVisitor (one per class) may seem like a lot of overhead, but the nice thing is that you only have to pay that overhead once: once this pattern has been added to your class hiearchy you can reuse it over and over again, whenever your callers want to do custom logic based on type. I hope the program below makes sense to you.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication33 {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
      var foo1=new Foo<ConcreteClass1>();
      var foo2=new Foo<ConcreteClass2>();
      var bar=new Bar(100);

      var result1=foo1.M(bar);
      var result2=foo2.M(bar);
      Debug.Print("result1.SomeProperty="+result1.SomeProperty);
      Debug.Print("result2.SomeProperty="+result2.SomeProperty);
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // these definitions can appear in project 1
  // notice that project 1 does not have any dependencies on Bar
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  /// <summary>
  /// This interface needs a line for each class in the hierarchy
  /// </summary>
  public interface IABCVisitor<out T> {
    T Visit(AbstractBaseClass x);
    T Visit(ConcreteClass1 x);
    T Visit(ConcreteClass2 x);
  }

  public abstract class AbstractBaseClass {
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// All of AbstractBaseClasses' children need to override this property
    /// </summary>
    public virtual T AcceptVisitor<T>(IABCVisitor<T> visitor) {
      return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
  }

  public class ConcreteClass1 : AbstractBaseClass {
    public override T AcceptVisitor<T>(IABCVisitor<T> visitor) {
      return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
  }

  public class ConcreteClass2 : AbstractBaseClass {
    public override T AcceptVisitor<T>(IABCVisitor<T> visitor) {
      return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // these definitions can appear in project 2
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public class Bar {
    public int MagicValue { get; private set; }

    public Bar(int magicValue) {
      MagicValue=magicValue;
    }
  }

  public class Foo<T> where T : AbstractBaseClass, new() {
    public T M(Bar bar) {
      T t=new T();
      t.SomeProperty=t.AcceptVisitor(new CalculateTheRightValue(bar));
      return t;
    }
  }

  public class CalculateTheRightValue : IABCVisitor<int> {
    private readonly Bar bar;

    public CalculateTheRightValue(Bar bar) {
      this.bar=bar;
    }

    public int Visit(AbstractBaseClass x) {
      throw new NotImplementedException("not implemented for type "+x.GetType().Name);
    }

    public int Visit(ConcreteClass1 x) {
      return bar.MagicValue+73;
    }

    public int Visit(ConcreteClass2 x) {
      return bar.MagicValue-12;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty classic application of the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Please explain, I don't follow.